# How to name downloaded files using strings from another column in the same dataframe?

Tags: r, loops

I have a a dataframe that looks like this:

```
link <- c("http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300366", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300664", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300627", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002205311830156X", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090951618303419", "http://hdl.handle.net/10.1093/jjfinec/nby006")
repec_id <- c("RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:19-44", "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:1-10", "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:58-68", "RePEc:eee:jetheo:v:182:y:2019:i:c:p:329-359", "RePEc:eee:worbus:v:54:y:2019:i:4:p:372-386", "RePEc:oup:jfinec:v:17:y:2019:i:3:p:462-494")
df <- data.frame(repec_id, link)
```

I have a loop that takes each of the links and downloads the file it leads to (or returns a warning/ error message if the link is broken). It looks like this:

```
urls <- df$link
output <- rep(NA, length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  output[i] <- tryCatch(
    {download.file(urls[i], paste0('~/Desktop/Dataset/', basename(urls[i])))}, 
    error = function(e) {NA},
    warning = function(w) {NA}
  )
}
```

However, rather than naming the file using the `basename` function, I would like to assign the matching `repec_id` followed by the relevant extension (e.g. '.pdf', '.txt', etc). In other words, I would like each file that I download to have the relevant `repec_id` as its name:

```
list.files()
"RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:19-44.pdf" "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:1-10.txt"  "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:58-68.aspx" "RePEc:eee:jetheo:v:182:y:2019:i:c:p:329-359.pdf" "RePEc:eee:worbus:v:54:y:2019:i:4:p:372-386.pdf" "RePEc:oup:jfinec:v:17:y:2019:i:3:p:462-494.txt"
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm a bit stuck. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How do you know what is the relevant extension? It is not present in `link` or `repec_id`.

Comment: Good question. The short answer is that I don't. I was hoping there was a way of figuring out what type of file this is? Maybe using http_status and content-type?

Comment: If not, that's fine. Happy just to use the repec_id as the file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could write a function passing URL and name of the file.

```
download_my_file <- function(url, name) {
   tryCatch(
     {download.file(url, paste0('~/Desktop/Dataset/', name))}, 
      error = function(e) {NA},
      warning = function(w) {NA})
}
```

and use `Map` to pass it for every `link` and `repec_id`.

```
Map(download_my_file, df$link, df$repec_id)
```

**data**

`link` should be characters so using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(repec_id, link, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```