# How to determine if files are PDFs or not in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 150,000 files that each have an identifier but no path name. They look like this:

```
files <– list.files()
head(files)
[1] "RePEc/bis/bisqtr/0002e" 
[2] "RePEc/bis/bisqtr/0004e" 
[3] "RePEc/fip/fedclv/01d"
```

The problem is that some are html, some are text files and some are PDFs but I have no way of knowing which is which without opening every file. I only want to keep the PDFs so is there know  a way to get R to check file types?

Thanks for whatever help you can provide!

Comment: why they don't have an extension

Comment: I downloaded each of them using names from another column. See my question (and the answer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240941/how-to-name-downloaded-files-using-strings-from-another-column-in-the-same-dataf

Comment: You could try the 'magic' bytes. On Unix, the `file` command does this, and there is CRAN package offering this:  https://cran.r-project.org/package=wand

Comment: Along with Dirk's comment: `system2("file", shQuote(filepath))` might work. It does not work on (my) windows with git-for-windows installed (magic files problem), but it works just fine on my ubuntu boxes. And also from Dirk's comment, `wand::get_content_type(filepath)` returns the string `"application/pdf"` (for me).

Comment: @r2evans this works! Thanks very much to you and Dirk for your help!